# How to get the Phone number provider Country code like +44 into String using Firebase Phone Auth in Android?

Tags: firebase, sms, firebase-authentication, phone-number

Please help me to get country code into String using Firebase phone authentication.

Comment: Hi GreatLeaner, Did you find any solution? I am stuck here..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the internal method of [PhoneNumberUtils](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/f4494c4a5fcafc8b32351edcb02ed2834c6a32b4/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/ui/phone/PhoneNumberUtils.java#L36) class which is present in Firebase for Android.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCodeValue = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
Log.d(TAG, "Countrycode: " + PhoneNumberUtils.getCountryCode(countryCodeValue));
```